# How to see network requests made by a swf

Tags: flash, networking, httpwebrequest

I have a swf (flash file) who is making http request.

Which is the easiest way to see what request the flash application is doing?

P.S. I do not have the program as a fla file

Answer (score 2):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if your on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: This app is really cool, but it's not showing any requests from Flash for me... Maybe it'll work for someone else. It shows a lot more than the Chrome network panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open it in a browser, try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Live HTTP Header](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) on firefox.